# WOW: functions UnitIsPlayer() change in 6.0?

Tags: lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

in a addon I have the following code:

```
elseif ( UnitIsPlayer("target") ~= nil ) then
    qui = UnitName("target",false)
    print ("SI7 pour cible: " .. qui)
    ma_fiche(qui,-1)
else
    lister_plaine()
end
```

up to 6.0 (WOD) when I run this code, with no target, I would go to else clause (`lister_plaine()`).

now it seems I Go to then clause (`qui= ...` ), and of course qui is `nil` and I get an error.

Has anyone else see a change in `UnitIsPlayer()` behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many functions were changed from the 1 or nil return values to true or false. This is probably the issue.

You may also have written like 'if ( UnitIsPlayer("target") )' which would have covered both cases, and is probably preferable.

Comment: thanks ! one can even use `if UnitIsPlayer("target") then ` (without c-style if() ).